# Mapping fields with special character # fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I mapped a field in elastic search so that it gets analyzed with an edge 2gram tokenizer:

```
"google.title.#t": {
  "type": "string",
   "index_analyzer": "edge_2gram_body_analyzer",
   "search_analyzer": "standard"
}
```

When I get the mapping, it seems healthy. I would expect this:

```
POST myIndex/_analyze?field=google.title.#t
{"test"}
```

to return the tokens:

```
te, tes, test
```

Yet, it does not, it returns "test" instead: it is defaulting to the standard analyzer.

Now, when I remove the # from the key (google.title.t), it works. Is there a way I can escape the # at mapping time? What are the other forbidden characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is becuase "***#***" in url needs to be [url-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)
Example:

```
POST myIndex/_analyze?field=google.title.%23t&text=text
```